# Update data in Firebase, Android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update data firebase but its not a user data, like its a request generated by admin[basically a management system] and im not using uid here [image],

here's my code for this

```
mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reports_uploads")

val upload = Reportsreq(
    name = binding.nameEditText.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' },
    imageUrl = mImageUri.toString(),
    email = binding.spinneremail.selectedItem.toString().trim(),
    feedback =  binding.descriptionEditText.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' },
)
val uploadId = mDatabaseRef!!.push().key
mDatabaseRef!!.child((uploadId)!!).setValue(upload)
openImagesActivity()
```

}

I'm trying to update the feedback herem but when update button is clicked it makes new child rather than updating it, and I'm unable to get the key which i set for for uploading the data.

```
val intss = intent
//val key = intss.getStringExtra("key")
val email = intss.getStringExtra("Email")
val name  = intss.getStringExtra("Name")
val desT  = intss.getStringExtra("DESCRIT")
val imgT  = intss.getStringExtra("IMGURI")

binding.nameDetailTextView.text =   name
binding.descriptionDetailTextView.text = desT
binding.emailTextView.text = email
binding.teacherDetailImageView.loadImage(imgT)
// binding.keyy.text = key

/* binding.updatebtn.setOnClickListener {

    val update : Reportsreq(
    feedback = feed.toString().trim()
    )*/
val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reports_uploads")
val feed= binding.updatefeedback.text.toString()
binding.updatebtn.setOnClickListener {
    if (feed.isEmpty()){
        //val  mDatabaseRefkey = database
        val key = database.getKey()
        database.child("key").child("feedback").setValue(feed)

        Toast.makeText(this, "updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Feedback not provided", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}
```

here the main problem is how i can get the key so that i can update the child from specific node

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please edit your question and add what Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Besides that, to understand better, do you need to update a field inside the `-NFmZ...0se5` node? If yes, which one?

Comment: Have you also considered taking into consideration Frank's advice?

Comment: Yes, you should add the code as text instead of a picture.

Answer (score 1):

To update the node you'll need to know its key somehow.

Once you know the key, updating the node is a matter of:

```
database.child("-FmZfoRezMxmCG90se5").child("feedback").setValue("New feedback")
```

If you don't know the key, you can update all nodes under a path with:

```
database.get().addOnSuccessListener {
    for (nodeSnapshot in it.children) {
        nodeSnapshot.ref.child("feedback").setValue("New feedback")
    }
}.addOnFailureListener{
    Log.e("firebase", "Error getting data", it)
}
```

*There might be some typos in that last snippet. If something doesn't compile, please try to figure it out from the error message and the reference documentation.*

Comment: The type of the object it's not needed when performing a for loop. So it should work now.

Comment: As I said in my answer: "you can update **all** nodes under a path with". If you don't want to update all child nodes, you need to know the key of the node to update. (@Alex: thanks for fixing my Kotlin code )

Comment: You're very welcome, puf.

Comment: "but mine is still the same" does not mean very much to me. If you don't want to update all child nodes, you need to know the key of the node to update.